# Custom attribute in .NET to execute code before and after decorated method?

Tags: .net, events, attributes

Ideally I'd like to find a way to do something like:

```
[MyCustomAttribute()]
public void MyMethod()
{
    Debug.Write("B");
}

public MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void OnBegin()
    {
        Debug.Write("A");   
    }

    public void OnEnd()
    {
        Debug.Write("C");
    }
}
```

Which would write:

> ABC

When MyMethod() gets excuted. Any ideas if this can actually be done? The ActionFilter attribute seems similar to this idea, but it only applies to MVC requests.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) - it pretty much does this already.

It is a post processor - it takes your compiled assembly, looks for the attributes and injects code into the decorated methods.